# TYPO3 cart extension lost cart after FE user login

Tags: typo3, cart, typo3-extensions

I have the EXT: cart running on my TYPO3 system. So far the cart extension works good, but if I put something on my cart and login with an FE user (e.g. after registration) the cart gets lost. Do anyone have an idea how I can login without losing the cart?

Comment: This is a default security setting which you can change in the install / admin tool somewhere in the global settings. I'm sorry I don't know the exact setting name but with the search in the settings you should easy find it, try to search for cookie

Comment: @SimonGilli just can find settings for the lifetime and permanent login but not for "taking" the session data after login. Do you remember the settings name? I only find `[SYS][features][security.frontend.keepSessionDataOnLogout]` but thats for logout. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLieser did you try it? I am under the impression that logging in a user is technically also a "logout" of the "default user".

Comment: Since it is working now without changing anything in install tool, I think it should work out of the box. I don't know what was wrong previously. Thanks!